# Dismissing UIActionSheet gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiactionsheet

I've got an application with UITableView nested in a UITabBarController, and I have a method that's giving me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when it's called from UIActionSheetDelegate method clickedButtonAtIndex:

The method that (sometimes) gives a problem is called updateTaskArray. Basically, it does a Core Data fetch that configures an NSMutableArray "taskArray" that's a property of the viewController (which the tableView delegate uses to configure its cells) then its last line is

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

The thing is, it works fine most of the time, but it only gives an error when it's called from the UIActionSheetDelegate. When I run it with NSZombieEnabled, it tells me

```
*** -[UITabBarButton setAlpha:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5c2e760
```

And with breakpoints, it doesn't give EXC_BAD_ACCESS until after the UIActionView delegate method (and updateTaskArray within it) complete. The UIActionSheet is presented with:

```
[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

so I'm wondering if this means that it's dismissing the actionSheet that is causing the problem... but it doesn't give any error if I don't call updateTaskArray from the delegate...

I'm not really sure what would be a good next step as [UITabBarButton setAlpha:] isn't a method I'm calling "myself" and the error seems to occur after the code I've actually "written" has already run- any suggestions on where to start approaching this one?

Comment: Check where you're `retain`ing/`release`ing `tabBarController` (if at all). If it's in your `.xib` but you're not `retain`ing it when you load the `.xib`, you should be - e.g with an `@property (retain)` in the object which loads the `.xib` for its view.

Comment: The tabBarController isn't loaded from a nib, it's created programatically. It's stored in a property of the app delegate: `@property (nonatomic, retain) UITabBarController *tabBarController;` and I never call release on it. The code in `didFinishLaunching` dealing with it is 
`self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc ] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nc1, nc2, nil];`

Comment: It does occur to me that updateTasks does change the tableViewController's title- which in turn does change the tabBarButton's title (by the default behavior of UITabBarController)- not sure if that plays a role or not. I'm not sure if that makes any difference or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed

```
[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

to

```
[actionSheet showFromToolbar:self.navigationController.toolbar];
```

And it now works fine. The tabBarController is the parent of the navigation controller, I reckon it didn't like me going one level above.

Comment: this problem seems to occur if you change the active tab in the action triggered by the action sheet.

Comment: +1 for ChristophK's comment. I have a similar problem; I'm displaying a view modally from an action sheet button. After closing the modal view, trying to show the action sheet again crashes the app(EXC_BAD_ACCESS). However, this solution doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your release statements.  You are releasing a UITabBarButton, or possibly the entire tab bar, when you shouldn't.  Review principles of memory management for iOS.

Comment: I've read principles of memory management, but at no point in the whole app do I ever release a UITabBarButton, or tabBar, or UItabBarController, so this advice doesn't seem to help much. I don't do anything with the tabBar itself at all except for init it with viewControllers in applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions: and launch the offending actionSheet with showFromTabBar.